# web-console does not appear on exception pages Rails 7.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently upgraded rails 7.0.8 app to rails 7.1.1. Now, I'm not getting the web console on exception pages. But when I put `console` somewhere in a controller, web-console pops up. The issue is on exception pages.

[image]

I'm using

- Rails 7.1.1
- Ruby 3.2.2
- web-console', '4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your application's configuration allows for the web console to be displayed on exception pages.

In your config/environments/development.rb file, you should have the following configuration:

```
config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But this was not supposed to do in rails 7.0. Is it a new thing in rails 7.1?

Comment: No problem! As far as I know, it has been available in Ruby on Rails for a while and is not specific to Rails 7.1.